# how can I handle "error" in communication to twitter.com? (ruby + twitter gem)

Tags: ruby, error-handling, twitter-client

I have nice piece of code that works. I tried to tweet the same text and I my script ended because `/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-0.9.4/lib/twitter.rb:87:in 'raise_errors': (403): Forbidden - Status is a duplicate. (Twitter::General)`

I know I cannot tweet the same text twice but I thought I will get the error inside the response variable.

How can I deal with the error? So my script will finish nicely not because of an error?

```
oauth = Twitter::OAuth.new('consumer token', 'consumer secret')
oauth.authorize_from_access('access token', 'access secret')

client = Twitter::Base.new(oauth)
response = client.update('Heeeyyyyoooo from Twitter Gem!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap any ruby statement or block of statements in `begin`..`rescue`..`end` to catch errors - you might want to try this:

```
begin
  oauth = Twitter::OAuth.new('consumer token', 'consumer secret')
  oauth.authorize_from_access('access token', 'access secret')

  client = Twitter::Base.new(oauth)
  response = client.update('Heeeyyyyoooo from Twitter Gem!')
rescue Twitter::General
  # Catch the error and do nothing
end
```

If you wanted to catch any error you can change the rescue line to just say `rescue`. You can read more about them [on the ruby-doc website](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html).

Comment: Getting an error is probably a bad thing tho, you might want to solve that issue rather than suppress the error - I'm not quite sure how its coming about.